# Automate Rest Webservice testing using jasmine node

Tags: web-services, rest, jasmine-node

We are having an requirement to automate REST web services testing with jasmine node. Im pretty new to web service testing and node js as well.
What exactly we need to test in web services?
Could you please also guide in order to automate REST services testing.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Answer (score 0):

A REST Web Service uses http verbs (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) to do various actions. So to test a web-service you need to write tests that send these requests with the appropriate data for your web-service and then examine the results. There are various test frameworks that make your life simpler.

Take a look at some simple tests I wrote for a sample REST Web-Service [here](https://github.com/sxm1972/resttest/blob/master/test/test.js). 
The tests I wrote were for the purpose of running in Mocha but Jasmine should not be too different. Here is a [great article](http://thejsguy.com/2015/01/12/jasmine-vs-mocha-chai-and-sinon.html) on Jasmine and Mocha and the differences and similarities between them.